# d3js adding an arrow head to a line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add a svg image as a marker-end of a line. But the style is not applying. This is what I have tried.

```
var g = d3.select('#svg').append('g');
var a = d3.select('#start');
var b = d3.select('#end');

g
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', Number(a.attr('x')) + Number(a.attr('width')))
    .attr('y1', Number(a.attr('y')) + Number(a.attr('height')) / 2)
    .attr('x2', Number(b.attr('x')))
    .attr('y2', Number(b.attr('y')) + Number(a.attr('height')) / 2)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', '2px')
    .style('marker-end', 'url("/assets/svg/tooltip_arrow_color.svg")')
;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marker properties can not be assigned a reference to a svg file. Marker properties are either assigned the value "none" or assigned a reference to a marker element listed in the defs element of the svg element. The marker element contains the svg code for drawing the marker. For example...

```
<svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" style="fill: black; stroke: none;"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="398" height="198" style="fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 1;" />
  <path d="M 100 75 L 200 75 L 250 125" style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 10; marker-end: url(#Triangle);" />
</svg>
```

Information on marker properties can be found at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElement

Comment: I need to add the marker to the line and later I will be moving the line. So, Can I add the line, defs,rect,path in a group together?

Comment: You can ignore the rect element in my example. It was just a border around the svg element. I applied the marker property to a path element, but you can apply it to your line element. In your example, you can add a defs element to the svg element. Add a marker element to the defs element. In the line element, set the end-marker property to reference the marker element. If you later move the line, the displayed marker will move with the line. Or you could place the line element in a group element and move the group element. Whether you use a group element is up to you.